# Removing default XML Tag name from Java Restful web service

Tags: xml, web-services, rest

I am facing issue in my REST webservice development on JAVA.

Problem: My webservice fetches data from SQL server database. It contains number of fields. There is one field that contains one XML tag. So I have to create XML file with all Database fields and append the XML tag to it.

Here I could fetch data from database and could build the XML file but I couldn't remove the default XML tag name.

How I can remove the default XML tag name? I have tried @XMLElement options but never succeed. Please help!

Current output:

```
<CardProfile>
    <cardID="1">
    <accountType>1</accountType>
    .
    .
    .   
    </card>
    <ProfileXML><Profile ID="1"><Signature>adfalfjalj/Signature></Profile></ProfileXML>
</CardProfile>
```

Desired Output:

```
<CardProfile>
    <card cardID="1">
    <accountType>1</accountType>
    .
    .
    .   
    </card>
    <Profile ID="1"><Signature>adfalfjalj/Signature></Profile>
</CardProfile>
```

Card.java

```
package pinpad.repositoryservice;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Card {
    private int CardID;
    private String CardHolderName;
    private String Track1Data; 
    private String Track2Data;
    private String Track3Data;
    private String PANNumber;
    private String ExpiryDate;
    private String CVV;
    private String Address;
    private String ZipCode;
    private String DriverID;
    private String AccountTypeCreditDebit;

    @XmlAttribute (name = "ID") 
    public int getCardID() {
        return CardID;
    }

    public void setCardID(int id) {
        this.CardID = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getCardHolderName() {
        return CardHolderName;
    }

    public void setCardHolderName(String CardHolderName) {
        this.CardHolderName = CardHolderName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getTrack1Data() {
        return Track1Data;
    }

    public void setTrack1Data(String Track1Data) {
        this.Track1Data = Track1Data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getTrack2Data() {
        return Track2Data;
    }

    public void setTrack2Data(String Track2Data) {
        this.Track2Data = Track2Data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getTrack3Data() {
        return Track3Data;
    }

    public void setTrack3Data(String Track3Data) {
        this.Track3Data = Track3Data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getPANNumber() {
        return PANNumber;
    }

    public void setPANNumber(String PANNumber) {
        this.PANNumber = PANNumber;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getExpiryDate() {
        return ExpiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(String ExpiryDate) {
        this.ExpiryDate = ExpiryDate;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getCVV() {
        return CVV;
    }

    public void setCVV(String CVV) {
        this.CVV = CVV;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getZipCode() {
        return ZipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String ZipCode) {
        this.ZipCode = ZipCode;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getDriverID() {
        return DriverID;
    }

    public void setDriverID(String DriverID) {
        this.DriverID = DriverID;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getAccountTypeCreditDebit() {
        return AccountTypeCreditDebit;
    }

    public void setAccountTypeCreditDebit(String AccountTypeCreditDebit) {
        this.AccountTypeCreditDebit = AccountTypeCreditDebit;
    }
}
```

CardProfile.java

```
package pinpad.repositoryservice;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "CardProfile")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CardProfile {

    @XmlElement (name = "Card")
    public Card cards = new Card();

    public String ProfileXML;

    /**
     * @return the cards
     */
    public Card getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    /**
     * @param cards the cards to set
     */
    public void setCards(Card cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    /**
     * @return the profileXML
     */
    public String getProfileXML() {
        return ProfileXML;
    }

    /**
     * @param profileXML the profileXML to set
     */
    public void setProfileXML(String profileXML) {
        ProfileXML = profileXML;
    }
}
```

CardProfileRepositoryService.java

```
package pinpad.repositoryservice;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

/*
 * Holds Card and Profiles and exposes REST interface to answer a profile and card data 
 * based on profile ID and card ID
 */
@Path("/cardprofile")
public class CardProfileRepositoryService {

    CardProfile cardprofiles = new CardProfile();

    @GET
    @Path("/query/")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public CardProfile getCardProfile(
                    @QueryParam("cardid") int CardID, 
                    @QueryParam("profileid") int ProfileID) {   

        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();

        databaseManager.getConfigProperties();
        databaseManager.getDataBaseConnection();
        cardprofiles = databaseManager.executeSprocGetCardProfile(CardID, ProfileID);
        databaseManager.closeDataBaseConnection();

        return cardprofiles;
    }
}
```

tag value come entirely from database. So I want to remove  tag name so it will be only Value.. .

Comment: Please add the code of your JAXB annotated class to your question.

Comment: Sorry, Please see code added in above question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that should work: instead of keeping XML as String in CardProfile you could have an actual Java object, Profile, which also have JAXB annotations. Then when you pull Profile String from database you would unmarshall it to Profile Object using JAXB, set that object to CardProfile.profile and then marshall whole CardProfile.

```
CardProfile {
  @XmlElement
  public Card cards;

  @XmlElement
  public Profile Profile;
 }
```

Sure it adds a bit of overhead so might not be desirable if you have high performance requirements but it would work. In general, unless your XML documents are large marshalling/unmarshalling should be fairly lightweight operations.